# using the AND clause with SQLite and Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to fetch a value by comparing two columns but my application crashes every time.

```
Cursor cursor= db.query(TABLE_IMAGES, 
                        new String[]{"_id"}, 
                        name +" = ?" + time +" = ?", 
                        new String[]{compareToThis, compare to that},  
                        null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
Cursor cursor= db.query(TABLE_IMAGES, 
                        new String[]{"_id"}, 
                        name +"=? AND " + time +"=?", 
                        new String[]{compareToThis, compareToThat},  
                        null, null, null);
```

Given that `name` and `time` variables are Strings, and `compareToThis` and `compareToThat` are the values for the parameters, that should work for you.